# How to disable mdl tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am using Material Design Lite on a project and I have some mdl-tab tabs in my settings page. However, some of the settings are only useful if certain conditions are met. I would like to have a tab which is disabled unless the conditions are met.

This is what I'm doing now, which doesn't work:

```
<div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
  <a href="#displaySettings" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Display</a>
  <a href="#deviceSettings" class="mdl-tabs__tab" disabled="disabled">Device</a>
  <a href="#measSettings" class="mdl-tabs__tab" disabled="disabled">Measurement</a>
</div>
```

Is there *any* way to do this? If so, how?

The project is in Cordova. So HTML, CSS, Javascript and JQuery answers are all welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved similar problem in my project. I know i am a bit late but I hope that this will maybe help someone in the future.

Render your page without classes or text.

```
<div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
    <a href="#displaySettings" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Display</a>
    <a id=deviceTab href="#deviceSettings"></a>
    <a id=measurementTab href="#measSettings"></a>
</div>
```

You should add listener on input(needed for your conditions) and when the conditions are met just add class (mdl-tabs__tab) and text (Device, Measurement).

You can do that with jQuery
    `$("#deviceTab").addClass("mdl-tabs__tab").text("Device");
    $("#measTab").addClass("mdl-tabs__tab").text("Measurement");`

If user deletes information needed you can just remove text and class again and he wont be able to click on tab.

```
<div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
   <a href="#displaySettings" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Display</a>
   <a id="deviceTab" href="#deviceSettings" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Device</a>
   <a id="measTab" href="#measSettings"class="mdl-tabs__tab">Measurement</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by removing the href attribute from the tag while still leaving the classes and link text.  This will keep the tab looking like a tab and when you want to enable it just add the href with the id of the tab panel you want to activate.